# converting a dictionary to dataframe where keys and values each have their own columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary d:

```py
d = dict({'foo': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'bar': ['d', 'e', 'f']})
```

how would I get a dataframe that looks like:

```
+-----+--------+
| Key | Values |
+-----+--------+
| foo | a      |
+-----+--------+
| foo | b      |
+-----+--------+
| foo | c      |
+-----+--------+
| bar | d      |
+-----+--------+
| bar | e      |
+-----+--------+
| bar | f      |
+-----+--------+
```

This doesn't answer my question:
[Dictionary with values as lists to pandas dataframe frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32894268/dictionary-with-values-as-lists-to-pandas-dataframe-frame)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'foo': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'bar': ['d', 'e', 'f']}

df = pd.DataFrame([[key, value] for key, values in d.items() for value in values], columns=['keys', 'values'])
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
  keys values
0  foo      a
1  foo      b
2  foo      c
3  bar      d
4  bar      e
5  bar      f
```

As an alternative you could use [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'keys': list(d.keys()), 'values': list(d.values())}).explode('values').reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
  keys values
0  foo      a
1  foo      b
2  foo      c
3  bar      d
4  bar      e
5  bar      f
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d).stack().sort_values()

df
#Out[2037]: 
#0  foo    a
#1  foo    b
#2  foo    c
#0  bar    d
#1  bar    e
#2  bar    f
```

Answer (score 1):

After `pandas` 0.25

```
pd.Series(d).explode().reset_index()
Out[114]: 
  index  0
0   foo  a
1   foo  b
2   foo  c
3   bar  d
4   bar  e
5   bar  f
```

Comment: This results in an error for me, and I'm on Pandas version 25.

Comment: Right, I should have included that. "ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 3"

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I am not sure why you have that error , are you using the same `d = dict({'foo': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'bar': ['d', 'e', 'f']})
` then `pd.Series(d).explode().reset_index()
`

Comment: I figured it out, it's entirely due to my own dumb mistake!